# jQuery Ajax retrieves either "success" or "reload" - testing for each?

Tags: jquery, ajax, reload

i'm rather new to ajax. However I've gotten quite far.

```
$.ajax({
        url: loadUrl,
        dataType: "html",
        timeout: 5000,
        cache: false,
        // async: false,
        success: function(html,textStatus) {
            $("div." + targetBox).html(html);
            console.log(textStatus);
```

If this function is called a div container on my page gets updated with the following html coming from the server as a json string.

```
’{"status":"reload", "data":"/ajax/mowl/1/comments"}’
```

the backend developer says, the status could either be "success" or "reload".

If status success comes in I simply want to show the data as a message.
If status reload comes in I want to reload the current div with the url passed in the data.

So right now when triggering this ajax function my div container simply gets inserted this ’{"status":"reload", "data":"/ajax/mowl/1/comments"}’ message as html. However I don't want that but rather want to check if the status coming with this is "success" or "reload" and then react to it.

Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your datatype should be JSON `dataType: json,`so:

```
url: loadUrl,
dataType: json,
...
success: function(data) {
if(data.succes == "reload"){
 // some AJAX here that gets the HTMl from data.data (in this case '/ajax/mowl/1/comments')
$("div." + targetBox).html(data.data);
 ...
```

here data in an object with the 'status' and 'data' elements, that you can access
this script will put the URL in the DIV

PS take a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/